# Writing to a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.4

```
with open("classA.csv" , "a", newline = "") as fp:
     a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter = ",")
     data = [("{0} has scored: {1} / 10\n ".format(name,score))]
     a.writerows(data)
```

I am trying to create a maths quiz that calculates the final result and then writes this result to an excel file. This is my code so far but when I look into excel, I see that the entire statement in data is stretched out across the row and would like this:

```
| B | o | b | h | a | s | s | c | o | r | e | d | : | 9 | / | 1 | 0
```

How would I be able to print out like this:

```
| Bob has scored: | 9/10 |
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: writerows expects an iterable of iterables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a tuple of columns in the list that you pass to `writerows`.

Each element in the tuple will be a column in the resulting file, and all the tuples in the list represent the rows.

For example, if you want to output:

```
Bob,2
Joe,3
Bill,5
```

Then you need to create a list like this:

```
[('Bob', 2), ('Joe', 3), ('Bill', 5)]
```

To implement the same in your example, try this version:

```
col1, col2 = '{} has scored:','{}/10'

with open('classA.csv', 'a') as fp:
   writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
   data = [(col1.format(name), col2.format(score))]
   writer.writerows(data)
```

You also don't need to add the `\n`

Answer (score 0):

your delimiter is ',' so you should try: `data = [("{0} has scored,{1} / 10\n ".format(name,score))]` or set the delimiter to ':'

Comment: The problem is that `writerows` is iterating over the string, the delimiter isn't a problem.